# How to access table datatype like an array?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I tried to store data in a table variable `@coordinates`, which contains 2 rows and 2 columns: latitude and longitude.

To store value:

```
declare @coordinates table(latitude decimal(12,9), longitude decimal(12,9)) 
insert into @coordinates select latitude, longitude from loc.locations where place_name IN ('Delhi', 'Mumbai')
```

to see the value:

```
select * from @coordinates
```

result:

```
latitude    longitude
28.666670000    77.216670000
19.014410000    72.847940000
```

But I want to access the values one by one like:
@coordinates[1][1] or @coordinates.latitude[1]

or any easy way possible?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have ARRAY type.

Comment: Ya it doesn't have so I used table datatype, but I want to know if any easy way is there to access the column and row one by one?

Comment: Maybe you've chosen the wrong tool for what you want to do? If you want access rows one by one, use any procedural language, you don't need RDBMS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `@coordinates` is a variable, it is a *table* variable, not an array. You access data stored in a table variable the same way you would access data in a conventional table, i.e. using a query.

Now when you want to retrieve data of a table's specific row, you need a way of referencing that row. Often you use some sort of an ID column. In this case you could add such column in your `@coordinates` declaration:

```
declare @coordinates table
(
  id int identity (1,1),
  latitude decimal(12,9),
  longitude decimal(12,9)
);
```

The `id` column is declared as an IDENTITY column and will be populated automatically as rows are added to `@coordinates`. So now after running your INSERT statement, the contents will look like this:

```
id  latitude      longitude
--  ------------  ------------
1   28.666670000  77.216670000
2   19.014410000  72.847940000
```

And in order to retrieve, say, `latitude` from row 1, you would do

```
SELECT latitude FROM @coordinates WHERE id = 1;
```

If necessary, you can use it as a scalar expression where appropriate, for example:

```
SELECT
  some_columns,
  (SELECT latitude FROM @coordinates WHERE id = 1) + another column AS some_alias
FROM
  some_table
WHERE
   ...
```

Granted, this is not as pretty as just `@coordinates.latitude[1]`, but it is a conventional way of working with data in SQL.

Note, though, that if you need to retrieve the contents of this table in a query involving other tables and the row ID is going to depend on some table's column, it will be more natural to *join* `@coordinates` to the corresponding table:

```
SELECT
  ...
  c.latitude + t.some_other_column AS whatever
FROM
  some_table AS t
  INNER JOIN @coordinates AS c ON t.some_column = c.id
WHERE
  ...
```

Comment: thanks. but i think the code `SELECT latitude FROM @coordinates WHERE id = 1` is going to hit database

Comment: Yes, under the covers a table variable is implemented as a local temporary table, so storing data into it as well as reading from it is going to hit the `tempdb` database.