# What is the optimized way to pass multiple parameter from a single table to a function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a function `[dbo].[FN_CalcAerialDistance]` which accepts `4 parameters` and returns its result.
Now that 4 parameters come from the `same table`, I do not want to hit Database multiple times to bring same data.
I have tried:

```
SELECT [dbo].[FN_CalcAerialDistance]
    (
       (select latitude from loc.locations where place_name = 'Delhi'),
       (select longitude from loc.locations where place_name = 'Delhi'),
       (select latitude from loc.locations where place_name = 'Mumbai'),
       (select longitude from loc.locations where place_name = 'Mumbai')
    )
```

> Any way to optimise the code? I have also tried [to access table datatype like an array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195771/how-to-access-table-datatype-like-an-array)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a complement to Edgars answer you can do it without declaring any variables as:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_calcaerialdistance (x.latitude
                                 ,x.longitude
                                 ,y.latitude
                                 ,y.longitude)
FROM loc.locations as x
CROSS JOIN loc.locations y
WHERE x.place_name = 'Delhi'
  AND y.place_name = 'Mumbai' ;
```

I wouldn't expect it to perform any better though.

In addition you can calculate several distances at once

```
SELECT x.place_name
     , y.place_name
     , dbo.fn_calcaerialdistance (x.latitude
                                 ,x.longitude
                                 ,y.latitude
                                 ,y.longitude)
FROM loc.locations as x
CROSS JOIN loc.locations y
WHERE x.place_name in ('Delhi', 'Bangalore') 
  AND y.place_name = 'Mumbai' ;
```

Comment: I like this because it clearly expresses the intent:  for each x/y pair of locations, calculate the aerial distance.

Comment: Still way cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot [@lennart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart)! Earlier I used loops to process data, now cross join has solved it. You can see my procedure (in the question description) : [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195842/how-to-prevent-duplicate-or-similar-data-from-getting-processed)

Answer (score 10):

This is the only thing I could think of. You could try this as a basis:

```
DECLARE
    @p1 DECIMAL(12, 9),
    @p2 DECIMAL(12, 9),
    @p3 DECIMAL(12, 9),
    @p4 DECIMAL(12, 9) ;

SELECT @p1 = latitude, @p2 = longitude 
FROM loc.locations 
WHERE place_name = 'Delhi';

SELECT @p3 = latitude, @p4 = longitude 
FROM loc.locations 
WHERE place_name = 'Mumbai';

SELECT dbo.fn_calcaerialdistance (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4) ;
```