# How to prevent duplicate or similar data from getting processed?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2016, duplication

I have a stored procedure which calculates the distance between 2 coordinate points:

```
CREATE PROC loc.CalcDistanceByPostalCode
(
@From VARCHAR(10),
@To   VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @data table (From_Place VARCHAR(200), From_Region VARCHAR(200), "To_Place" VARCHAR(200), To_Region VARCHAR(200), Distance decimal(8,2))
    DECLARE @postal1 table (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), place_name VARCHAR(200), region_name VARCHAR(200), latitude decimal(12,9), longitude decimal(12,9))
    DECLARE @postal2 table (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), place_name VARCHAR(200), region_name VARCHAR(200), latitude decimal(12,9), longitude decimal(12,9)) 

    INSERT INTO @postal1 SELECT distinct l.place_name, l.region_name, l.latitude, l.longitude 
                         from loc.locations l 
                         cross join loc.locations_postal lp 
                         where postal_code like @From and lp.city_id = l.ID
    INSERT INTO @postal2 SELECT distinct l.place_name, l.region_name, l.latitude, l.longitude 
                         from loc.locations l 
                         cross join loc.locations_postal lp 
                         where postal_code like @To and lp.city_id = l.ID

    INSERT INTO @data 
    SELECT
        t1.place_name,  t1.region_name, t2.place_name, t2.region_name,
        loc.FN_CalcAerialDistance(t1.latitude, t1.longitude, t2.latitude, t2.longitude) -- Function calculates Distance
    FROM @postal1 as t1
    CROSS JOIN @postal2 as t2
    WHERE t1.latitude <> t2.latitude and t1.longitude <> t2.longitude

    DECLARE @Distance decimal(8,2) = 0
    select * from @data order by Distance desc
    SELECT @Distance = Distance from @data
    return @Distance;
END
```

It calculates correct result if `@From` and `@To` are different, but gives redundant data if `@From` and `@To` are same.

Example: Different `@From` and `@To`:

```
EXEC loc.CalcDistanceByPostalCode @From = '110%', @To = '400%'`
```

Result:

```
From_Place  From_Region To_Place     To_Region      Distance
Delhi       Delhi        Mumbai      Maharashtra    1160.65
New Delhi   Delhi        Mumbai      Maharashtra    1157.80
Delhi       Delhi        Vasai-Virar Maharashtra    1115.68
New Delhi   Delhi        Vasai-Virar Maharashtra    1112.87
```

Example: Same `@From` and `@To`:

```
EXEC loc.CalcDistanceByPostalCode @From = '110%', @To = '110%'`
```

Result:

```
From_Place  From_Region To_Place    To_Region   Distance
New Delhi   Delhi       Delhi       Delhi       3.51
Delhi       Delhi       New Delhi   Delhi       3.51
```

**Do I need to write extra code to check if Distance is same then compare the From_Place with To_Place with the rows having the same distance? or any optimised way to prevent the duplicate data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow found a solution to fix the issue

> **I added more condition to the stored procedure query which calculated distance: @From <> @To OR t1.ID > t2.ID**

```
WHERE t1.latitude <> t2.latitude and t1.longitude <> t2.longitude and (@From <> @To OR t1.ID > t2.ID)
```

---

Thanks [@Ahmad.Tr](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/109827/ahmad-tr) for the `t1.ID > t2.ID` conditon.

It gave correct results, so I optimized the stored procedure: (execution time takes 35 to 52 seconds for 2767634 rows, earlier it was more than 2 times more records and also 2 times slower.

```
CREATE PROC loc.CalcDistanceByPostalCode
(
@From VARCHAR(10),
@To VARCHAR(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @postal1 table(ID int IDENTITY(1,1), place_name VARCHAR(200), region_name VARCHAR(200), latitude decimal(12,9), longitude decimal(12,9))
    DECLARE @postal2 table(ID int IDENTITY(1,1), place_name VARCHAR(200), region_name VARCHAR(200), latitude decimal(12,9), longitude decimal(12,9)) 

    INSERT INTO @postal1 SELECT distinct l.place_name, l.region_name, l.latitude, l.longitude from loc.locations l cross join loc.locations_postal lp where postal_code like @From and lp.city_id = l.ID
    INSERT INTO @postal2 SELECT distinct l.place_name, l.region_name, l.latitude, l.longitude from loc.locations l cross join loc.locations_postal lp where postal_code like @To and lp.city_id = l.ID

    SELECT
        t1.place_name "From_Place", t1.region_name "From_Region", t2.place_name "To_Place", t2.region_name "To_Region",
        loc.FN_CalcAerialDistance(t1.latitude, t1.longitude, t2.latitude, t2.longitude) as "Distance" -- Function calculates Distance
    FROM @postal1 as t1
    CROSS JOIN @postal2 as t2
    WHERE t1.latitude <> t2.latitude and t1.longitude <> t2.longitude and (@From <> @To OR t1.ID > t2.ID)
    order by Distance desc
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `And t1.ID > t2.ID` to the where clause , it will make sure that the join happens once .
To the following query

```
SELECT t1.place_name, t1.region_name, t2.place_name, t2.region_name, loc.FN_CalcAerialDistance(t1.latitude, t1.longitude, t2.latitude, t2.longitude) -- Function calculates Distance 
FROM @postal1 as t1 CROSS JOIN @postal2 as t2 
WHERE t1.latitude <> t2.latitude and t1.longitude <> t2.longitude
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclamer: I don't know sqlserver, so there may be syntactical errors. I would aim for getting rid of the variables, at a glance this appears to be what you are trying to do:

```
WITH postal (postal_code, place_name, region_name, latitude, longitude) as (
    SELECT distinct lp.postal_code, l.place_name, l.region_name
         , l.latitude, l.longitude 
    FROM loc.locations l 
    JOIN loc.locations_postal lp
         ON lp.city_id = l.id
    WHERE postal_code like @From
       OR postal_code like @To
)
SELECT t1.place_name,  t1.region_name, t2.place_name, t2.region_name
     , loc.FN_CalcAerialDistance(t1.latitude, t1.longitude
                                ,t2.latitude, t2.longitude)
    FROM postal as t1
    JOIN postal as t2
        ON (t1.latitude, t1.longitude) <> (t2.latitude, t2.longitude)
```

If:

```
(t1.latitude, t1.longitude) <> (t2.latitude, t2.longitude)
```

is not supported, this is eqvivalent to:

```
t1.latitude <> t2.latitude OR t1.longitude <> t2.longitude
```

Comment: thanks. but inner joins made the program run slower.  I somehow solved: added condition: `and (@From <> @To OR t1.ID > t2.ID)`.